# Grails: <g:select

Tags: grails

How can I achieve the following:

I have a boolean stored in my Domain, by default Grails creates a checkbox as a control. I want a select control with values : Active/Inactive.
On selecting `Active` the value `True` should be passed 
and 
On selecting `InActive` the value `False` should be passed.

How can I achieve this using

```
<g:select name="status" from="" optionKey="" value=""  />
```

Much appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't know if this is the best approach, but you could have an enum to do the work:

```
public enum SelectOptions{
    ACTIVE(true, 'Active'),
    INACTIVE(false, 'InActive')

    Boolean optionValue
    String name

    SelectOptions(boolean optionValue, String name){
        this.optionValue = optionValue
        this.name = name
    }

    static getByName(String name){
        for(SelectOptions so : SelectOptions.values()){
            if(so.name.equals(name)){
                return so;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    static list(){
        [ACTIVE, INACTIVE]
    }

    public String toString(){
        return name
    }
}
```

Add an instance of the SelectOptions enum to your domain:

```
class MyDomain {
    SelectOptions selectOptions = SelectOptions.ACTIVE
    //Other properties go here

    static constraints = {
        selectOptions(inList:SelectOptions.list())
        //other constraints
    }
}
```

Then in your GSP view:

```
<g:select
    name="status"
    from="${myDomainInstance.constraints.selectOptions.inList}"
    value="${myDomainInstance.selectOptions}" />
```

In your controller's save method, you need to get the correct enum from the String value submitted by the view:

```
def save = {
    SelectOptions selectOption = SelectOptions.getByName(params.status)
    def myDomainInstance = new MyDomain(params)
    myDomainInstance.selectOptions = selectOption
    // proceed to save your domain instance
}
```

Comment: Thanks Cesar for your reply, however when I click create I get the following error   


Failed to convert property value of type java.lang.String to required type com.myCompany.SelectOptions for property status; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [com.myCompany.SelectOptions] for property status: no matching editors or conversion strategy found

Comment: Yes, the problem basically is that from the GSP you submit a String, but the domain object expects an enum. I edited my answer to reflect that.

Comment: Note that with this technique that you end up with a varchar with the values 'Acive' or 'Inactive', instead of a bit in the database.

Comment: Note for Internet Future Users: This approach is *ugly*. It couples presentation concerns with Model logic, which is not very nice at all. Optimally this should be handled by directly modifying the view, not leaning on scaffolding on cases where the default is not enough.

Answer (score 0):

Ok After a lot of brainstorming I could figure it out

My Code is simpler and goes like this:

```
package exproj.masters

 public enum ExamDurationTypes{
    FULL_EXAM(1, 'For Whole Exam'),
    PER_QUESTION(2, 'Per Question')

    Integer optionValue
    String name

    ExamDurationTypes(Integer optionValue, String name){
        this.optionValue = optionValue
        this.name = name
    }

    static getByName(String name){
        for(ExamDurationTypes edt : ExamDurationTypes.values()){
            if(edt.name.equals(name)){
                return edt;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
    static list(){
        [FULL_EXAM, PER_QUESTION]
    }

    public String toString(){
        return optionValue
    }

}
```

Then I added it to my Domain class

```
class Exam {
.
.
.

Integer durationType

    static constraints = {
        durationType(inList: ExamDurationTypes.list())
    }   

}
```

In my GSP Page I cracked it like this

```
<g:select
name="durationType"
from="${exproj.masters.ExamDurationTypes.values()*.getName()}"
keys="${exproj.masters.ExamDurationTypes.values()*.getOptionValue()}"
value="${examInstance.durationType}" />
```

Finally produces this:

```
<select name="durationType" id="durationType">
<option value="1">For Whole Exam</option>
<option value="2">Per Question</option>
</select>
```

Enjoy Coding